# Using a function as function parameter

Tags: python, nested-function

I tried to write a nested function to calculate the area.  However, the program showed the name `circle` is not defined.

Could anyone please help providing a suggestion about this nested function problem?
What concept is missing from the below code?

```
def area(shape, n):
    def circle(radius):
        return 3.14*radius**2
    def square(length):
        return length*length

print(area(circle, 10)   #system return -> name 'circle' is not defined
print(area(square, 5)   #system return -> name 'square' is not defined
```

Comment: `What concept is missing from the below code?` - [Binding of names, Resolution of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#execution-model), [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: The concept you're missing is that everything defined inside a function, including nested functions, are *local* to their container.

Comment: There shouldn't even be nested functions in this case.

Comment: Some good Q&A's searching with `python functions in a class or module site:stackoverflow.com` or `python function grouping site:stackoverflow.com` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *encapsulating* those in a function, put them in a module.

area.py...

```
def circle(radius):
    return 3.14*radius**2
def square(length):
    return length*length
```

Then use them by importing `area` :

other.py

```
import area
q = area.circle(10)
z = area.square(5)
```

another.py

```
import area
shape = 'circle'
q = getattr(area,shape)(10)
shape = 'square'
z = getattr(area,shape)(5)
```

and.py

```
from area import circle,square
q = circle(10)
z = square(5)
```

Comment: It seems that `circle` should not be implemented as a nested function. I suspect that OP has a spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

Circle is only defined in the scope of the area funcion. Functions are just like any other variable, you can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp).

```py
def circle(radius):
    return 3.14*radius**2

def square(length):
    return length*length

def area(shape, n):
    return shape(n)

print(area(circle, 10)
print(area(square, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since The functions are nested inside of area. Circle and square won't be recognised outside of the area function. I don't know if you need them to be nested. But you can just put them outside of the area function.

```
def circle(radius):
    return 3.14*radius**2
def square(length):
        return length*length

def area(shape, n):
    if shape == circle:
        print(circle(n))  

    if shape == square:
        print(square(n))  

area(circle, 20)
area(square, 20)
```

There are a lot of ways to do this.

```
def area(shape, n):
    if shape == "circle":
        return 3.14*n**2 

    if shape == "square":
        return n*n 

print(area("circle", 20))
print(area("square", 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* have nested functions, but you can't access them unless they are, for example, returned from that inner scope:

```py
def area():
    def circle(radius):
        return 3.14*radius**2
    def square(length):
        return length*length
    return circle,square

circle, square = area()

print(circle(10))
print(square(5))
```

Output:

```
314.0
24
```